# keycloak error http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/claim-dev/protocol/openid-connect/token

Tags: jwt, keycloak

i'm trying to explore keycloak but i get error
http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/claim-dev/protocol/openid-connect/token

client image
[image: client setting image]

postman req
[image: postman image]

error log

```
    19:47:49,701 ERROR [org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler] (default task-52) Uncaught server error: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.endpoints.TokenEndpoint.checkSsl(TokenEndpoint.java:220)
            at org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.endpoints.TokenEndpoint.processGrantRequest(TokenEndpoint.java:176)
            at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor551.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:138)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:517)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:406)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$0(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:370)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:356)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:372)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:344)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:137)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:106)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:132)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:100)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:440)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:229)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:135)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:356)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:138)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:215)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:227)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
            at org.keycloak.services.filters.KeycloakSessionServletFilter.doFilter(KeycloakSessionServletFilter.java:91)
            at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
            at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
            at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
            at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
            at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
            at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
            at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
            at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
            at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
            at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
```

Comment: So you got a NullPointerException. Wonder how we could help, knowing nothing about the backend...

Comment: thanks for your response, i have already updated the question and have attached the configuration. my keycloak version is 8.0.1

Answer (score 4):

You also need client_secret. If everything is properly configured you will get tokens (Client ->Settings "Authorization Enabled" and "Direct Access Grants Enabled" should be set to "ON")

Comment: thanks for your response, but i'm still getting error. i attached the configuration on my question.

Comment: When I try to get token without client_secret I get 400 - Bad Request and {
    "error": "unauthorized_client",
    "error_description": "Client secret not provided in request"
}. When I add client_secret I get access and refresh tokens. It seems something is wrong with your realm. Can you try to get tokens from master realm?